# MS Windows 10 and Boot Security option in BIOS

Tags: kernel, certificate, windows-10, driver, sign

I'm a developer of kernel drivers for Windows.  Usually I sign them by using a standard DigiCert Code Signing Certificate. It worked for all Windows.

But the last year the MS released the 1607 version of Windows 10 and my drivers signed by DigiCert certificate passed without a sign after the OS boot.

I found the cause - this is an option Security Boot in BIOS. If I enable that option, then  the OS loads my driver without a sign.  If I disable the option, then  it's OK, my driver loads with a sign. The Boot Security does not affect on the drivers signed  by Microsoft.

Now is my question: if I sign a driver by  an EV DigiCert certificate, will this problem will go out?

Answer (score 0):

For MS Windows 10 we must use EV certificate.

The short instruction:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt484189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396